# Print multiple full sized iframes in a single print out

Tags: javascript, iframe, printing

Is it possible to print multiple full sized iframes in one print (one iframe per paper)? I know it's possible to print a full sized iframe with:

```
window.frames["name"].focus();
window.frames["name"].print();
```

It's also possible to loop through it if you have several iframes, although this separates them into different prints, like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < window.frames.length; i++) {
   window.frames[i].focus();
   window.frames[i].print();
}
```

So is there a way to organize this into one single print?